# A simple Inequality problem

Tags: inequality

[image]

Can't I eliminate $p^3$ from both side and say that quantity A is greater?

Comment: mind you, when p<0, then the sign reverses. You could divide by p² though if that would become easier. Is this a GRE question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a problem with dividing both sides by $p^3$: what if $p \leq 0$?

We have to consider cases:

If $p \gt 0$ then $q\gt t$

If $p = 0$, we know nothing of the relationship between $q$ and $t$.

If $p\lt 0$ then the inequality changes direction, and $t\gt q$

Comment: If $p=0$ then you have $0>0$, so you don't have $p=0$ :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputations to post a comment. But think of what is the result going to be if p=0.

Comment: Since it is not true that $0>0$, then $p=0$ is not possible.

Comment: The question asks whether the inquality holds for any p or not. So p = 0 is a possiblity that makes the inquiality false

Comment: @Gotaquestion -- The format seems to imply that one is to *assume* that $qp^3>tp^3.$ This assumption implies that $p \neq 0$, so that $p \neq 0$ is an assumption of the problem, and cannot be used as the basis of a counterexample.

Comment: No, the question asks if the first inquality is true, what can be said about the relative values $q,t$. Nowhere does it say "for all $p$." @Gotaquestion

Comment: I think the trick in the question was to see if someone will divide both sides by p^3 or not. Knowing that p is NOT zero, anyone could simply divide both sides by p^3 and the inequality would be correct all the time. The only exception is p = 0, that makes dividing by p illegal @coffeemath

Comment: @gotaquestion As other comments have pointed out, assuming $p$ is NOT zero, there are two cases left, $p>0$ and $p<0$. If $p>0$ then $q>t$, i.e. quantity A is greater, while if $p<0$ then $t>q$, i.e. quantity B is greater. Hence "cannot determine" is the answer.